# Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=26 "file is not a database". After updating to Flutter 2.0

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, sqlcipher

I tried to update Flutter to version 2.0.5 and Dart language from 2.10.4 to 2.12 version since from that moment I had a lot of errors.

I tried several ways including re-installing Pods and also to go back to the previous Flutter version but now I get an error when running in iOS only (not in Android!).

I would enourmously appreciate if you could help me in some way.

This is the error message in the console:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           46,1s
Waiting for iPhone 11 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50334/emMoKYaYe0M=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11...
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=26 "file is not a database" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=file is not a database}) sql 'SELECT * FROM Devices' args []}
#0      SqfliteSqlCipherDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite_sqlcipher/src/factory_sql_cipher_impl.dart:44:9)

#1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:211:15)
#2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawQuery. (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:403:36)
#3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized. (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:336:22)
#4      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:32:26)
#5      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:332:33)
#6      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawQuery (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:402:12)
#7      Sqflit<…>

This is the current situation with Flutter doctor:

/Users/Sergio/Development/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale it-IT)
• Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/Sergio/Development/flutter
• Framework revision 7891006299 (4 months ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
• Engine revision ae90085a84
• Dart version 2.10.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/Sergio/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
• CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin installed
• Dart plugin version 201.9335
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
• iPhone 11 (mobile)                 • E3DBA180-42B0-4FBD-9D17-496B53A33A59 • ios         • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)

• No issues found!

This is what inlcuded in the pubspec.yaml file:

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
sqflite_sqlcipher: ^1.1.1
url_launcher: ^5.7.10
grouped_list: ^3.5.0
flappy_search_bar: ^1.7.2
syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^18.3.35
package_info: ^0.4.3
purchases_flutter: ^1.4.0
shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
firebase_core: ^0.5.1
firebase_analytics: ^6.2.0
persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^2.1.0
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
loading_overlay: ^0.2.1
webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.3.5
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
path_provider: ^1.6.14

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

Answer (score 2):

Try running `pod update` in your pod file

Comment: Already tried several times to run Pod update, also Repo Pod update, deleting the Podfile.lock before to update

Comment: I guess there is a dependency issue with SQLCipher but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Just write sqflite_sqlcipher:    without any version number. Also do flutter update

Comment: Can you give the exit error appearing when you do ```pub get``` @user15690472

Comment: No exit error when I do pub get. App starts with no issues, it crashes when try to open the database file

Comment: Any update on this? I am now having the same issue after updating to Flutter 2.5.2

Comment: @thamey I also have this error